# Prometheus for some data already generated

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am just starting to get the concept of what [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) is, and I have done a couple of examples already.
I can understand how Prometheus monitors some data, even the one generated by itself and also some data related to a python application for example.

My question is more simple though. If I have a text file of data already generated (for example some metric of something), is there a way for this data be fed to Prometheus so that I can generate queries or visualize the data?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. If you actually have text files with data you want to analyze I'd suggest you to write the data to another TMDB (InfluxDB for example) or a plain old SQL database and then connect it with Grafana. Also take a look at PowerBI. I prefer it for data that is scoped more towards business analytics than monitoring.

Long answer: There is a unpublished HTTP API that allows you to push metrics in the JSON format. See the following two issues:

https://github.com/kube-reporting/metering-operator/issues/640

https://github.com/kube-reporting/metering-operator/issues/656

Answer (score 0):

While it is impossible to import historical data to Prometheus, such data can be imported to Prometheus-like systems such as VictoriaMetrics. See [these docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-import-time-series-data) for details.